# Not recieving string discord py

Tags: python, discord

This is my code it doesn't print "return"
I made this code but when i run the event the funtion trigger but dont return please help!!!
I tried everything but it won't work please help.

```
def get_temp_id(guild):
    with open('tempchannelchan.json', 'r') as f:
        tempchannelchan = json.load(f)
        print("check")
    return tempchannelchan[str(guild.id)]
    print("return")
        
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('tempchannelchan.json', 'r') as f:
        tempchannelchan = json.load(f)
    tempchannelchan[str(guild.id)] = ''
    with open('tempchannelchan.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(tempchannelchan,f)

@client.command()
async def settempchanchan(ctx, *, chan):
    guild = ctx.guild
    with open('tempchannelchan.json', 'r') as f:
        tempchannelchan = json.load(f)
    tempchannelchan[str(guild.id)] = chan
    with open('tempchannelchan.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(tempchannelchan,f)
    await ctx.send('Saved channel')


@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    guild = member.guild
    temp_id = get_temp_id(guild)
    if before.channel is None and after.channel.id == temp_id:
        await member.send("Alarm!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `return` call will always end the current function and return to the calling function. Therefore, your `print` statement is never reached since it comes after you leave the function.